# Javascript and Query string issue

Tags: c#, javascript, html, adsense

When ever I pass variables in my Query string some java script does not show up. 
It only happens when the url looks like this.. default.aspx?yesId=1&noId=27  if its just default.aspx the java script shows just fine.

Do you have any idea why?  Or how to fix it? Is there another way to dis play this javascript code?

Default.aspx The code thats does not display is in the bottom Div tag "ads"

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div id="Direction">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Click on the girl you like better." Font-Size="Large"
        Width="270" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#1B0358"></asp:Label>
</div>
<div id="pictures">
    <div id="ratedpic">
        <p>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">
                <asp:Label ID="RatedPicnameLabel" runat="server" Text="" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label></asp:HyperLink>
        </p>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="RatedImage" Width="70%" runat="server" /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="RatedPicRating" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
    </div>
    <div id="MainPics">
        <div id="RightPic">
            <p>
                <asp:Label ID="FirstPicMemberNameLabel" runat="server" Text="" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
            </p>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="FirstPicLink" Width="90%" runat="server" OnClick="FirstPicLink_Click" />
        </div>
        <div id="LeftPic">
            <p>
                <asp:Label ID="SecondPicMemberNameLabel" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="White"
                    Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
            </p>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="SecondPicLink" Width="90%" runat="server" OnClick="SecondPicLink_Click" />
        </div>
        <div id="skip">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LBNoChoice" PostBackUrl="~/default.aspx" ForeColor="White" runat="server">Skip - I Can't Choose</asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Ads">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google_ad_client = "ca-pub-**MyPubCode**";

        google_ad_slot = "**AdCode**";
        google_ad_width = 728;
        google_ad_height = 90;

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
    </script>
</div>
```

Code Behind page

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //get query string
        if (Request.QueryString["yesId"] != null && Request.QueryString["noId"] != null)
        {


            int yesPictureId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["yesId"]);
            int noPictureId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["noId"]);
            RatedImage.Visible = true;
            HyperLink1.Visible = true;
            RatedPicRating.Visible = true;

            //pass ratings
            Ratings PassRatings = new Ratings();
            PassRatings.InsertRatings(yesPictureId, 1);
            PassRatings.InsertRatings(noPictureId, 2);

            //Get total yes and nos and Do Calculation 

            Ratings GetNoVotes = new Ratings();
            int DATotalYesVotes = GetNoVotes.GetTotalNOVotes(1, yesPictureId);
            int DaTNoVotes = GetNoVotes.GetTotalNOVotes(2, yesPictureId);
            int DaTotalVotes = DATotalYesVotes + DaTNoVotes;
            double Percentage = ((double)DATotalYesVotes / (double)DaTotalVotes) * 100;
            //Round percentage
            Percentage = Math.Round(Percentage, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
            //Percentage = Convert.ToUInt32(Percentage);
            //TotalyesVotes.Text = Percentage.ToString();

            //Insert New percentage
            Picture UpdatePictureTating = new Picture();
            UpdatePictureTating.UpdateRatings(yesPictureId, (int)Percentage);


            //Create pictue object
            Picture RatedPic = new Picture();
            DataTable DARatedPicture = RatedPic.GetRatedPicByQueryString(yesPictureId);

            //Assign Location and Rating to variables
            foreach (DataRow row in DARatedPicture.Rows)
            {
                // firstRatedPicId = row["PicID"].ToString();
                //secondNoPicId = firstYesPicId;
                //holds member Id for profile link
                int MemberID = (int)row["MemberID"];
                RatedPicnameLabel.Text = row["MemberName"].ToString() + "'s profile";
                HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "Member.aspx?UserID=" + MemberID;
                RatedPicRating.Text = "Banged Rating: " + row["PicRating"].ToString() + "%";
                RatedImage.ImageUrl = "Pictures/" + row["PicLoc"];
                RatedImage.PostBackUrl = "Member.aspx?UserID=" + MemberID;
            }
            //RatedImage.Enabled = false; 

            //Get


        }
        else
        {
            RatedImage.Visible = false;
            HyperLink1.Visible = false;
            RatedPicRating.Visible = false;
        }


        Picture dlPicture = new Picture();
        DataTable DTPictures = dlPicture.GetRandomPicture();





        Picture dlPicture2 = new Picture();
        DataTable DTPictures2 = dlPicture2.GetRandomPicture();



        // the variables to hold the yes and no Id's for each set
        string firstNoPicId = "";
        string firstYesPicId = "";
        string secondNoPicId = "";
        string secondYesPicId = "";

        foreach (DataRow row in DTPictures.Rows)
        {
            firstYesPicId = row["PicID"].ToString();
            secondNoPicId = firstYesPicId;
            FirstPicMemberNameLabel.Text = row["MemberName"].ToString();
            FirstPicLink.ImageUrl = "Pictures/" + row["PicLoc"];

        }


        foreach (DataRow row in DTPictures2.Rows)
        {
            secondYesPicId = row["PicID"].ToString();
            firstNoPicId = secondYesPicId;
            SecondPicMemberNameLabel.Text = row["MemberName"].ToString();
            SecondPicLink.ImageUrl = "Pictures/" + row["PicLoc"];

        }
        while (firstYesPicId == secondYesPicId)
        {
            DTPictures2 = dlPicture2.GetRandomPicture();

            foreach (DataRow row in DTPictures2.Rows)
            {
                secondYesPicId = row["PicID"].ToString();
                firstNoPicId = secondYesPicId;
                SecondPicMemberNameLabel.Text = row["MemberName"].ToString();
                SecondPicLink.ImageUrl = "Pictures/" + row["PicLoc"];

            }
        }
        FirstPicLink.PostBackUrl = "default.aspx?yesId=" + firstYesPicId + "&"+"noId=" + firstNoPicId;
        SecondPicLink.PostBackUrl = "default.aspx?yesId=" + secondYesPicId + "&"+"noId=" + secondNoPicId;


    }
```

Comment: I would also consider using the refactor tool inside VS to refactor the Page_Load() it looks a bit too much and no very readable it's up to you.. just a suggestion.. also I would add some IsPostBack check what if you are not triggering postbacks not sure once again just a suggestion..

Comment: How would i Check IsPostBack? What would that do?

Comment: If there is code that you would only want to execute the first time the page is loaded and not on a postback, you would wrap it inside a check like so: if (Page.IsPostBack){//code goes here}

Comment: there is an if statement you can write if(IsPostBack){}

Answer (score 0):

Could you create something like this and test the Request / Response

```
HttpRequest q = Request;
string v = q.QueryString["yesId"]
    if (v != null)
    {
    }
    v = q.QueryString["noId"];
    if (v != null)
    {
    }
```

Comment: I modified it a bit and I still get go Javascript once i have a query string in the url.

Comment: HttpRequest q = Request;
            string v = q.QueryString["yesId"];

            string J = q.QueryString["noId"];
            if (v != null && J != null)
            {

Comment: cool my point is I was wanting to know if that would help you to see if you have results or not..

Comment: yes there is results Im getting a no and yes id I can write those to the page every time.

Comment: if you are wanting to display the DIV tags I am pretty sure you can assign values to those tags the same way by the Div tags ID or name. I do more service oriented programming not so I've been away from Web dev for a while i beleive Div's trigger postbacks as well you will have to double check by stepping thru your code.